# 100 Scratches, easy fix?

Tags: rust, paint-scratches

My girlfriend parked her car (metalic blue Golf V) and took a piece of the solid pillar. So we have a bunch scratches on the left rear. It's about 100 tiny scratches, some are big, others smaler. Some are down to the body.
It's ugly, but we don't care.

- I don't want to spend thousands of euros
- I don't want to sand it down and repaint it.
- I don't want to "Touch Up"- paint every single scratch
- I don't want to make it uglier.

So my Question is, can I just spray some transparent varnish on top of all the scartches ? Will will it still look good? Will it prevent rust?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It would help to see a photograph of the damage.  For small scratches, some cutting compound followed by polish and wax should yield good results with no need to apply any fresh paint.

*Edit*

Having seen the damage, I'm afraid that the car will need more than just a polish.  It looks as though she's dented the wheel-arch so the car needs, at best, a dent puller and some fresh paint applied.

Comment: I added a picture.

Comment: for me the dent doesn't matter ;) what do you mean by fresh paint? that would be kind of expensive :( Don't you think covering it with transparent spray would keep it clean from rust? Thats my only mission :D preventing rust.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do anything, but you want it to look good and prevent rust? Hmmm...

Spraying automotive clear coat over it will preserve it as it looks now. To do that effectively would require some surface prep sanding, which you said you don't want to do.

If you are looking for a "least amount of effort" solution, only use touch-up paint on the scratches that go to the metal and leave the rest alone.

Answer (score 1):

can of rustoleum spray paint and a [bandaid sticker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0098DCZ4E) but it will probably not look good but then again I drive a suzuki samurai with at least 3 dents per body panel.

You can also ignore it.

I would not suggest farnish.

Either way make sure you clean the surface really well.

If it is a bumper cover you can get used painted ones for $200 usd depending on the make and model.

Comment: Maybe transparent rustoleum is the solution, depends on wether it washes away or it sticks like paint. How does it behave?

Comment: @Basti its a brand of paint usually comes in spray cans. not sure if they have clear or not. it is famous for stopping rust.